# lost my iPhone 4s and its offline

Tags: iphone

I lost my iPhone 4s the other day and I went on find my phone but it said it was offline, so I clicked lost mode but have been checking every day, what does it mean by offline? is it cos the phone is off or that it doesn't have internet or broken? if someone has stolen the phone surely they cant use it? as I put it in lost mode or if they did could I at least track it? or is there a way they can get round this? I'm so confused and lost without my phone :(

Answer (score 4):

Offline means that either:

1. Your iPhone is turned off
2. You have no WiFi
3. You have no cellular data connection

If you have iOS7 and iCloud enabled, there is no way they can restore your iPhone. This is because you have to enter your Apple Id when you try to disable iCloud.